# how do I make a brand new shopify app write a file when a webhook action is being called?

Tags: shopify, remix, hydrogen, shopify-hydrogen

New App is created using shopify cli with remix.js

currently in webhooks.js

```
`import { authenticate } from "../shopify.server";
import db from "../db.server";

export const action = async ({ request }) => {
  const { topic, shop, session } = await authenticate.webhook(request);

  switch (topic) {
    case "APP_UNINSTALLED":
      if (session) {
        await db.session.deleteMany({ where: { shop } });
      }
      break;
    case "CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST":
    case "CUSTOMERS_REDACT":
    case "SHOP_REDACT":
    default:
      throw new Response("Unhandled webhook topic", { status: 404 });
  }

  throw new Response();
};
`
```

let's say I want to write a file everytime the carts_create webhooks is being called , How Would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fs

```js
    case "CARTS_CREATE": 
      if (session) {
        const cartData = await request.json(); is JSON
      fs.writeFileSync("cart_data.json", JSON.stringify(cartData, null, 2));
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**